# Oracle APEX - LOV from LDAP

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ldap, oracle-apex

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to create an LOV item where the values are the email from LDAP. 
Anybody knows if it's possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

1. Make a PL/SQL [`PIPELINED`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#i53109) function that queries your LDAP with [`DBMS_LDAP`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/dev.1111/e10186/dbmsldap_ref.htm#OIMAD009) and returns a table of emails,
2. Define your `LOV` item as query-based:

   ```
   SELECT column_value display, column_value FROM TABLE(function)
   ```

Comment: I've used Vincent's solution successfully, specifically for an ApEx application. If you end up wanting another column (like email, displayname, title) you will probably need to create a type object and then make pipelined returns of that object type. Make sure to unbind at the end of your pipelined function, by the way.

Comment: Also, almost equally important:  you will need to catch EXCEPTION
      "when no_data_needed" and perform an unbind there as well. Here is the very interesting reason:  http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2010/04/nodataneeded-something-i-learned.html